# VB6 - Line Numbering at build time

Tags: command-line, vb6, numbers, line

One of the cool things about VB6 is that if you add a line numbers to your code is that the ERL function will return it if an error occurs.

I use MZ-Tools for VB6 to add line numbers to the entire project, which is really cool, however, it's a pain to work with code that is numbered.  So I typically remove the lines while I work on it.

I was wondering whether there is a command line way to add/remove line numbers using either MZ-Tools or something else?  I'd like to incorporate it into the build process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Googling turned up these tools which, apparently, are command-line tools that will add line numbers and then build the project. I haven't tried them.

- [Visual Basic Expert](http://www.visualbasicexpert.com/visualbasicexpert/Tools_LineNumbering.aspx) - freeware
- [VB Builder](http://www.gridlinx.com/builsum.htm) - $30 at the time of typing
- [VB Watch Protector](http://www.aivosto.com/vbwatch.html) - $300 at the time of typing, but it does many other things besides.

You'd want to hook this up with your version control system and check in the line-numbered code.

BTW the [VB6 discussion group](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion) is an excellent place to Google for this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I once downloaded a great tool for line numbering VB6 applications during the build process (I think from a forum) but I've since lost the original location and author.  I went and posted the tool [here on my blog](http://www.contactandcoil.com/software/vb6-line-numbering-build-tool/), at least until someone tells me where the original code is, and who the author was.

It's a GUI tool with a command line interface and Windows shell integration.  Not bad.  It comes with the source code in VB6, so it's pretty nifty.  I've used it successfully.

Comment: +1. The VBP company name says "www.visualbasicexpert.com". That website no longer exists, but the WaybackMachine has some snapshots.  Seems to be a Lewis Tandy. [Homepage](http://web.archive.org/web/20070212095337/http://www.visualbasicexpert.com/), [project page which lists a line numbering project](http://web.archive.org/web/20061102082709/http://artshop.dotnet11.hostbasket.com/visualbasicexpert/tools.aspx) Maybe I should quit software and become a private detective :)